# How can I get a calculation in this Calculation Code?

Tags: java, calculation

I need a little help here. The question is the output (PS! the last output line).The program only prints only number 2 on the last line. How can I get the calculation. Thank You!

Output is here:

Choose from the following calculations:
1: subtraction
2: addition
3: multiplication
4: division
5: remainder

Make your choice: 1

Type in the first number: 9
Type in the second number: 7

9 - 7 = 2

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Calculation
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Choose from the following calculations:");
        System.out.println("1: subtraction");
        System.out.println("2: addition");
        System.out.println("3: multiplication");
        System.out.println("4: division");
        System.out.println("5: remainder");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("\nMake your choice:");
        int choice = input.nextInt(); 

        if( 1 <= choice && choice <= 5 )
        {
            System.out.print("\nType the first number: ");
            int first = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Type the second number: ");
            int second = input.nextInt();

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                System.out.println(+ (first - second));
                break;
                case 2:
                System.out.println(+ (first + second));
                break;
                case 3:
                System.out.println(+ (first * second));
                break;
                case 4:
                System.out.println(+ ((double)first / (double)second));
                break;  
                case 5:
                System.out.println(+ (first % second));
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid choice");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean only prints number 2 on the last line?

Comment: The Output last line must be  9-7=2 and mine prints only umber 2.

Comment: You need to print the things you want displayed. At the moment you’re only printing the answers, but you want to print at least 5 things: first, the symbol, second, equals sign, the answer

Comment: You could try: `first+" + "+second+" = "+(first+second)`, `first+" - "+second+" = "+(first-second)` and so on.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
System.out.println(first+"-"+second+"="+(first-second));

System.out.println(first+"+"+second+"="+(first+second));

System.out.println(first+"*"+second+"="+(first*second));

System.out.println(first+"/"+second+"="+((double)first / (double)second));

System.out.println(first+"%"+second+"="+(first%second));
```

P.S you are not considering Divide by zero error for your division.